# Typo in Baby Rudin?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Exercise 3.12
  Suppose $a_n>0$ and $\sum a_n$ converges. Put
$$r_n=\sum_{m=n}^\infty a_m.$$

a) Prove that 
$$\frac{a_m}{r_m}+\cdots+\frac{a_n}{r_n}>1-\frac{r_n}{r_m},$$
if $m>n$ and deduce that $\sum\frac{a_n}{r_n}$ diverges.

If we want $>$, then each denominator on the LHS should be replace with the largest denominator. If $m>n$, then $r_m<r_n$. So shouldn't the RHS be

$$1-\frac{r_m}{r_n}?$$

Comment: The left hand side of the displayed equation (the sum of fractions) would normally be written with increasing indices, suggesting that what's intended is $"if $n > m$, and deduce that..."  So maybe there is a misprint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my edition of Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis (third edition) This is the exercise in question.

[image]

In my copy it reads $m<n$ but you typed it as $m>n$ above, hence the confusion.

Comment: Pulled out my copy of baby Rudin, was about to submit the same!

Comment: Yes. Quite right. Thank you. :)

Comment: @TimRaczkowski As for proof technique, as I expect you noticed, it helps to replace all of the denominators to the largest denominator (in this case $r_m$) and then notice that the top $(a_m+\dots+a_n)$ resembles a difference of two $r$ terms.

Comment: Yes. I'm not having a problem with the proof. Just the notation. :)